# How to mask text in EditText when the view loses focus.

Tags: android, android-edittext

So if a user enters "1234"  they will see "1234" in the EditText field.  but when that field loses focus I want it to show "****"

So I've implemented a custom TransformationMethod that will only mask the entered text if the EditText field does not have focus.

when I enter the text "12345" it shows it as it should "12345" but when I click on a different field the numbers never get masked. I want to see "*****" but I still see the same "12345"

If I rotate the device though (force it to reload everything) it correctly shows "*****".  And when I click on the EditText Field it correctly changes the masked text from "*****"   to "12345"  So it works when gaining focus but not when losing focus.  I've tried implementing an OnFocusChangeListener but it seems to have no affect.

**Is there any way I can force the EditText Field to redraw the text when it loses focus?**

SetUp:

```
 editText.setTransformationMethod(CustomPasswordTransformationMethod(numUnobfuscatedDigits))
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
                    ((EditText)view).invalidate()    
                     ((EditText)view).refreshDrawableState()
```

CustomPasswordTransformationMethod:
    public class CustomPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
        private int unObfuscated = 1;
        private boolean mIsFocused = false;

```
    /**
     * @param number the number of digits that will be unObfuscated at the end of the input string. Must be a positive integer or 0.
     */
    public CustomPasswordTransformationMethod(int number) {
        if (number < 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid parameter number =" + number + " number of un-obfuscated digits must be a positive integer or 0.");
            unObfuscated = 0;
        }
        unObfuscated = number;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChanged(View view, CharSequence sourceText,
                               boolean focused, int direction,
                               Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(view,sourceText,focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        mIsFocused = focused;
    }


    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;

        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }

        public char charAt(int index) {
            if(mIsFocused) return mSource.charAt(index);
            else {
                if (index < ((length()) - unObfuscated)) return '●';
                return mSource.charAt(index);
            }
        }

        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }

        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if it does what you need.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            editText.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else{
            editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know we should avoid "thank you" comments but seriously thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to keep it simple:

```
String password = "";

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editText.setText(password, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        } else {
            password = editText.getText().toString();
            String ofuscated = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){ ofuscated += "*"; }
            editText.setText(ofuscated, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a great idea, unfortunately I need the underlying text to stay the same since we save the entire string to the data base every time an edit is made. Using the password TransformationMethod keeps the underlying text "12345" when it gets passed as an Editable to the TextWatcher.